# Cocos2d. Diffuse image (60 fps)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, graphics, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

The game was created by support cocos2d 0.99.5 and Box2d.
Iphone SDK 4.3

We have a character. When a character moves quickly, it looks blurred (fuzzy // unfocused). On a simulator and on device (iPhone 3G).

To move a character using mouseJoint (dampingRatio = 0 // frequencyHz = -1).

In the screenshot image clearly. [link](http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/6995/fish01g.png)

The character is focused. The screenshot not transfer problems.

All the time 60 fps.

Tried params:

- use kCCDirectorProjection2D // 3D
- alies // antialies to texture params
- CC_COCOSNODE_RENDER_SUBPIXEL 1 and 0

Video sample: [link](http://youtu.be/9sDd-fmwRcc)

How to get a clear image of the character during the move?

Comment: Noting that using AliasTexParameters, a character can be seen a little better

Comment: It probably just looks fuzzy because it's moving. The screenshot shows that the image is being rendered correctly.

Comment: Yeah, but the movie, if you pause it, shows that the moving fish is definitely blurry compared to the still fish.

Comment: Carter, in other games (other developers) are clear.
For the experiment, I took a pencil and put it to a sheet of paper began to move quickly. Eyes see a pencil in focus, then problem is not an optical effect, a code problems

Comment: Jim Buck, yes, you're right. What does this mean?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm using a bit of Cocos2d-x on a project, but not enough that I can say what would cause that blur. The fact that you tried turning on and off the subpixel seems like a good first thing to try. Maybe confirm the texcoords on the moving object to see if they are offset a bit? Seems very unlikely, though. As I hit "pause" at different points in your movie, it seems less blurry than other points. If it only looked blurry in Y, I would say that it must be a subpixel thing, but it looks equally blurry in X.

Answer (score 3):

I also had a problem like this and fixed it by changing this line in ccConfig.h:

`#define CC_FIX_ARTIFACTS_BY_STRECHING_TEXEL 0`

to

`#define CC_FIX_ARTIFACTS_BY_STRECHING_TEXEL 1`

This is the comment for this define, maybe it helps someone.

```
   /** @def CC_FIX_ARTIFACTS_BY_STRECHING_TEXEL
 If enabled, the texture coordinates will be calculated by using this formula:
   - texCoord.left = (rect.origin.x*2+1) / (texture.wide*2);
   - texCoord.right = texCoord.left + (rect.size.width*2-2)/(texture.wide*2);

 The same for bottom and top.

 This formula prevents artifacts by using 99% of the texture.
 The "correct" way to prevent artifacts is by using the spritesheet-artifact-fixer.py or a similar tool.

 Affected nodes:
    - CCSprite / CCSpriteBatchNode and subclasses: CCLabelBMFont, CCTMXTiledMap
    - CCLabelAtlas
    - CCQuadParticleSystem
    - CCTileMap

 To enabled set it to 1. Disabled by default.

 @since v0.99.5
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that what you are describing is an optical illusion. LCDs, especially lower-quality LCDs, have a finite [response time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_time_%28technology%29). If this response time is too slow, it can cause ghosting, i.e. the moving object looks smeared. Basically what's happening is the previous frame's (or several frames') pixels take a long time to actually "turn off" and you see fainter versions of your sprite left behind as it moves.

With regards to your comment:

> For the experiment, I took a pencil and put it to a sheet of paper
>   began to move quickly. Eyes see a pencil in focus, then problem is not
>   an optical effect, a code problems

Looking at a moving object in the real world is not the same as looking at a moving object on the screen, with or without a poor display response time. The real-world object moves continuously, but the screen object moves in discrete steps. Your eye can follow the pencil exactly and keep the image sharp on your retina. If you follow a screen image, however, your eye moves smoothly, while the screen image "jumps" from place to place. This can cause a "juddering" effect for sufficiently fast-moving objects, even at high framerates. If 60fps is still juddery, there is basically no way around this; it is a limitation of current technology.

Comment: Hit "pause" on the movie he posted. This is not an optical illusion.

Comment: @Jim Buck: Yes, I saw the video, which is compressed at low-quality. I would expect faster-moving objects to look worse under compression. Even accounting for that, the sprite in the video doesn't look that blurry. The fact that he can't capture the artifact with a screenshot doesn't help either. That alone suggests the problem is somewhere in between the display buffer and the OP's brain. At this point I'm not convinced that the issue is real, and for now, a well-known screen artifact seems like a simpler explanation to me.